# How do I fit n data points with an (n-1)-degree polynomial

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I'm trying to fit, for example, 5 data points to a polynomial of degree 4. This is my code:

```
linex = array([1,2,3,4,5])
liney = array([23.0, 28.521, 36.31542, 49.2312312, 78.231312])
p,sp = polyfit(linex, liney, deg=4, cov=True)
print p
print sp
```

When I try to run something as simple as that, I get

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,5) (0,)

Supposedly it is an error with line 608 in polynomial.py in polyfit, where it says

```
return c, Vbase*fac
```

The fitting works if I change `deg = 3`, but that is not what I am looking for. Both arrays `linex` and `liney` have 5 points each as well. A brief search did not find a solution that addresses my problem.

Comment: You're [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting) the data, and I suspect this is what Numpy is complaining about.  Numpy often spits out unhelpful internal errors when you try to do something nonsensical, and it doesn't really make sense to fit a model with n parameters to a set of n datapoints.

Comment: Am I mistaken in the fact that it takes a 4th-degree polynomial to fit 5 points? Sure, there are 5 parameters encoded in the 4th-degree polynomial; so would that mean I need an (n-2)-degree polynomial to fit n points instead?

Comment: It sounds like you're actually looking for [polynomial interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation).  `polyfit` instead performs [polynomial regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression).  Give me a moment and I'll write this up as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally polyfit finds solution `Ax = y` equation using least squares where `A` is [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix). For degree 4 and 5 points this equation has exact solution (A has shape `5x5`, x - `5x1`, y - `5x1`). `numpy.linalg.lstsq` function returns numpy array with shape `()` in this case as estimate of error instead of returning vector with zeroes and code in `polyfit` fails to recognize that. However cov matrix (as it is computed there now) would be zero matrix even if it would recognized that. So to workaround it you can assume that cov matrix is zero matrix in your code for all degrees `deg >= number_of_points - 1` or just call `polyfit(linex, liney, deg=4)` if you don't need covariance matrix.

Excerpts from docs:

polyfit

> ```
> The solution minimizes the squared error
>
> .. math ::
>     E = \\sum_{j=0}^k |p(x_j) - y_j|^2
>
> in the equations::
>
>     x[0]**n * p[0] + ... + x[0] * p[n-1] + p[n] = y[0]
>     x[1]**n * p[0] + ... + x[1] * p[n-1] + p[n] = y[1]
>     ...
>     x[k]**n * p[0] + ... + x[k] * p[n-1] + p[n] = y[k]
>
> The coefficient matrix of the coefficients `p` is a Vandermonde matrix.
> ```

and numpy.linalg.lstsq:

> ```
> Return the least-squares solution to a linear matrix equation.
>
> Solves the equation `a x = b` by computing a vector `x` that
> minimizes the Euclidean 2-norm `|| b - a x ||^2`.  The equation may
> be under-, well-, or over- determined (i.e., the number of
> linearly independent rows of `a` can be less than, equal to, or
> greater than its number of linearly independent columns).  If `a`
> is square and of full rank, then `x` (but for round-off error) is
> the "exact" solution of the equation.
>
> Parameters
> ----------
> a : (M, N) array_like
>     "Coefficient" matrix.
> ```
>
> ... returns: ...
>       residuals : {(), (1,), (K,)} ndarray
>           Sums of residuals; squared Euclidean 2-norm for each column in
>           `b - a*x`.
>           If the rank of `a` is < N or M <= N, this is an empty array.
>           If `b` is 1-dimensional, this is a (1,) shape array.
>           Otherwise the shape is (K,).

Comment: I do need the covariance matrix to find errors in the fitting parameters, in fact.

Comment: Mathematically there is no error in fitting in such case, because exact solution of equation is found.

Comment: Ah I see. That does make sense - that's why polynomial interpolation wouldn't work for me. Thanks!